# where to save images in iOS app

Tags: ios, image, nsdocumentdirectory

In my app user will have a list of items, each item will have a thumbnail,the thumbnails are downloaded from the net, so i want to save the images in the app directory, so that the app won't download thumbnails every time, now i am saving images in `NSLibraryDirectory`, and there are many directories available like `NSDocumentDirectory,NSApplicationSupportDirectory..` those images will be downloaded if they are not present in the NSLibraryDirectory.My question is which directory is the correct place to save these thumbnail images so the user need not download the images every time. Previously i used `NSDocumentLibrary` but i have read that those will be backed up by iCloud and apple could reject the app for that. So, i have changed to `NSLibraryDirectory` and everything is working fine. Is it okay to do so. Any better way to store images like that.Thank you

Comment: Documents directory can be used for storing images. http://stackoverflow.com/a/6907432/366346 . can you post a link where it says its bound to be rejected by apple if used ?

Comment: [File System Programming Guide](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html)

Comment: You might want to read the File System Programming Guide, https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html

Comment: in file system programming guide it says save the file that cannot be recreated by the app, but the thumbnails can be recreated. But i want them to be saved,so that the user don't have to download each time opening the app..

Comment: This may be helpful: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11641375/771231

Comment: @Desdenova that link helped, i have removed the backup option for the file.. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Here is all about this:

https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/FileManagement/Conceptual/FileSystemProgrammingGuide/FileSystemOverview/FileSystemOverview.html

I prefer to store thumbnails in temporary directory which system clears automatically. I also wrote class which is responsible for cache files in directory you set.

http://github.com/tomkowz/TSFileCache

Answer (score 0):

it's downloading and retrieve images memory waste. better use: https://github.com/nicklockwood/AsyncImageView

Comment: previously i have implemented the same functionality downloading the images asynchronously showing an activity indicator, but the client wants to save the image on phone and don't want a activity indicator..

Comment: so better remove activity indicator ... otherwise download first time and save.... next time u can get that image...