# NSTemporaryDirectory or documentDirectory : Which one is safest to store data?

Tags: ios, swift, alamofire, nsfilemanager

I am using Alamofire for download data from the server.
I wanted to save in directory whichever is the safest place(DocumentDirectory, NSTemporaryDirectory). Could anyone help me in this?

**DocumentDirectory**:

```
   let destination: DownloadRequest.DownloadFileDestination = { _, _ in
        let documentsURL = FileManager.default.urls(for: .documentDirectory, in: .userDomainMask)[0]
        let fileURL = documentsURL.appendingPathComponent(fileName)

        return (fileURL, [.removePreviousFile, .createIntermediateDirectories])
    }
```

**NSTemporaryDirectory**

```
    let fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath:  
    NSTemporaryDirectory()).appendingPathComponent(fileName)
    let destination: DownloadRequest.DownloadFileDestination = { _, _ in
            return (fileURL, [.createIntermediateDirectories, 
.removePreviousFile])
        }
```

Comment: Since you are saving data in the disk it really doesn't matter.

Comment: 1 is permanent, 1 is temporary, what do they have anything to do with security?

Answer (score 5):

`NSTemporaryDirectory` will be wipe out data once your iOS device is running out of memory. So you can store temporary data on `NSTemporaryDirectory` like caching images and other stuff.

`NSDocumentDirectory` is useful to store data for long time.

So as per your need you need to use these directories to store data.

For more info please check [is saving in NSDocumentDirectory okay?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11632636/is-saving-in-nsdocumentdirectory-okay)